# Issues with escaping characters when reading Excel file in Pandas

Tags: pandas, escaping

I have an Excel file (xlsx) that I am trying to read into pandas with read_excel, but there are double quotes ("") in the spreadsheet causing line breaks at in correct points in the data frame.

I know you can escape characters when reading in CSVs but is there a way to do the same thing with read_excel?

The ultimate goal is to convert each tab of this excel file into individual csv's, so if there is an alternative method to read_excel that can get around the double quotes issue and ultimately end up as a csv, then that is fine as well.